# How to import Component Object Model (COM) in Java?

Tags: java, com, tlb, comobject

I have a COM object with extension `.tlb`. How do I import it in Java and use it in my code?

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to Component Object Model (COM), a binary-interface standard for software components introduced by Microsoft in 1993 then have a look at https://notendur.hi.is/snorri/SDK-docs/getstart/javac003.htm